# How to port stlport ifstream(HANDLE) to MS stl ifstream?

Tags: windows, stl, stlport

I'm currently porting code from stlport 5.1.3 to stl with MSVS 2010. I'm facing a problem and I hope someone can help me.

Somewhere in the code is:

```
HANDLE lHandle = CreateFileW(...);

ifstream lStream( lHandle );

// more job here...
```

This builds with stlport because the basic_ifstream has a cTor that takes a void*. But standard stl doesn't. I should write something like:

```
ifstream lStream( /*FileName*/ );
```

...but my file name is a **wchar_t** *. ifstream cTor only takes **char** *...

Do you know a work around?

Thanks in advance,

Dominique

Comment: Notice that the same is true for ofstream ...

Comment: I think most of the STL classes have wide-character variants; in this case wifstream has a ctor that takes wchar_t*.

Comment: You're right. It seems it was not the case with the VS2005 version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that stl included in MSVC2010 provides all the stuff I needed but it was not in the doc.

CreateFile was use because the former std::fstream could not handle wide char file name. Now, it has a cTor and a open() member for that.

Also, the new flavor of ifstream allows the programmer to set a sharing protection mode. I needed that also and it was done by CreateFile...

Thus, the "new" stl give me all the power I needed. Just a little flaw in the doc.